# MySQL 5.7 Community Edition Crash after disk partition resize

Tags: mysql, database

I have a serious problem with a `MySQL Community` edition based database which crashed and won't start back up after the database partition was resized.
The db is on an `RHEL7.2 Linux lvm` partition, which had to be reduced due to some storage issues.

During the resize there were inode issues which resulted into database files and folders to be moved into lost+found, and we recovered the files and moved them into the correct location.
Restarting the mysql service is resulting in these errors:

```
    2017-06-12T09:38:12.510405Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-06-12T09:38:12.510568Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2017-06-12T09:38:12.510628Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.13) starting as process 40601 ...
2017-06-12T09:38:12.515354Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2017-06-12T09:38:12.515396Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-06-12T09:38:12.515404Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-06-12T09:38:12.515413Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-06-12T09:38:12.515421Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-06-12T09:38:12.515428Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-06-12T09:38:12.515779Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-06-12T09:38:12.515943Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-06-12T09:38:12.518004Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-06-12T09:38:12.527531Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-06-12T09:38:12.529516Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2017-06-12T09:38:12.541493Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-06-12T09:38:12.542896Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 8204 in the system tablespace does not match the log sequence number 435564720566 in the ib_logfiles!
2017-06-12T09:38:12.542919Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-06-12T09:38:12.542926Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-06-12 10:38:12 0x7f4e11608740  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139973275715392 in file fut0lst.ic line 85
InnoDB: Failing assertion: addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >= FIL_PAGE_DATA
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
09:38:12 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68189 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0xef0cfb]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x461)[0x7af361]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf100)[0x7f4e111ef100]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x7f4e0fbe25f7]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x7f4e0fbe3ce8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x77f71c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z22trx_undo_free_preparedP5trx_t+0x0)[0x77f4d4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z19trx_undo_lists_initP10trx_rseg_t+0xdcc)[0x10bcacc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x10a11ec]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x10a39bc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24trx_sys_init_at_db_startv+0x1883)[0x10aaa43]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z34innobase_start_or_create_for_mysqlv+0x4830)[0x10721a0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xf39451]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x51)[0x7fa2b1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xce3925]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0x610)[0xcea830]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x7a82bd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x842)[0x7a97e2]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f4e0fbceb15]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x79f5e5]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

And:

```
2017-06-12T09:38:12.542919Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-06-12T09:38:12.542926Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-06-12 10:38:12 0x7f4e11608740  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139973275715392 in file fut0lst.ic line 85
InnoDB: Failing assertion: addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >= FIL_PAGE_DATA
```

I've tried multiple innodb_force_recovery modes and mysqld did not start until I used innodb_force_recovery = 6. When mysqld is started I cant backup the databases due to multiple errors like this:

```
2017-06-12T11:10:52.217568Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `mysql`.`plugin` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 2
2017-06-12T11:10:52.277914Z 0 [ERROR] Function 'validate_password' already exists
2017-06-12T11:10:52.277954Z 0 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'validate_password' with soname 'validate_password.so'.
2017-06-12T11:10:52.284445Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `mysql`.`gtid_executed` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 18
2017-06-12T11:10:52.293339Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2017-06-12T11:10:52.310829Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2017-06-12T11:10:52.313911Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2017-06-12T11:10:52.314120Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2017-06-12T11:10:52.314139Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2017-06-12T11:10:52.314179Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-06-12T11:10:52.433825Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `mysql`.`server_cost` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 19
2017-06-12T11:10:52.449122Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `mysql`.`engine_cost` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 20
2017-06-12T11:10:52.476635Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `mysql`.`time_zone_leap_second` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 12
2017-06-12T11:10:52.477431Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `mysql`.`time_zone_name` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 8
2017-06-12T11:10:52.490830Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `mysql`.`time_zone` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 9
2017-06-12T11:10:52.507804Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `mysql`.`time_zone_transition_type` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 11
2017-06-12T11:10:52.508725Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `mysql`.`time_zone_transition` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 10
2017-06-12T11:10:52.513876Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `mysql`.`servers` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 3
2017-06-12T11:10:52.563565Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2017-06-12T11:10:52.563876Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.13'  socket: '/dataspace/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

And when I try to dump the database files I see this:

```
mysqldump -uroot -pXXXXX --skip-lock-tables --skip-extended-insert --hex-blob office > office_dump.sql
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to `MySQL` server during query when dumping table `audit_log` at row: 334202
```

Please what can I do to recover the data and bring the database back online?

Any assistance would be seriously appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to get MySQL running again:

1. Backed up the borked $MYSQL_HOME directory.
2. Added `skip-grant-tables` to allow me login to mysql as root without passwords.
3. Tried different `innodb_force_recovery` modes in /etc/my.cnf till one allowed mysqld to start up. (In my case, it was `innodb_force_recovery = 5`).
4. Tried and failed to dump all the databases:

   `mysqldump -uroot -pXXXXX --skip-lock-tables --skip-extended-insert --hex-blob databasename > databasename_dump.sql
   mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
   mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table`audit_log`at row: 334202`
5. Got myself some Percona support and they suggested I loop through the *.frm files in each database directory in $MYSQL_HOME, and create individual mysqldump commands for each one. (Didnt know that the frm files represented the individual database tables inside of a database before then). They also suggested I `sleep` after each command to avoid the `Lost connection` problems.
   I wrote a script like this:
   `for table in $(ls -1 *.frm); do table_name=$(echo $table | cut -d '.' -f 1);  echo  mysqldump  --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root --skip-lock-tables databasename ${table_name} \> database.${table_name}.sql; echo sleep 5 >> commands.txt;  done`
   which generated all the mysqldump commands I could use to dump each database table.
6. I looped through created commands.txt file to dump all the tables that could still work.(`sh -x commands.txt`)
7. I started up a fresh mysql instance, created the lost database(s), and imported all the .mysql files dumped into the new databases.
   `for each in $(ls -1 $MYSQL_HOME/recoveries/*); do mysql -uroot -pXXXX databasename < $each; sleep 5; done`
8. Made sure the database was running and fixed other issues related to missing tables (`mysqlfrm --diagnostic` on a similar server helped)
9. When everything was finished, the server was back online, albeit with several months of critical data lost.